# Filled array detected as true

Tags: php, arrays

I receive an array from a method, and I check the value of it. If the array equals to true, it should do something, but if not, it has to do something else. Here's my if statement :

```php
$existence_status = $model->getReportExistenceStatus($validFormData['start_date'], $validFormData['end_date'], $validFormData['start_hour'] . ":00", $validFormData['end_hour'] . ":00");

var_dump($existence_status);

if ($existence_status) {
    // Report was not found, continue processing a complete API request

    // Get the report from the model
    $report_data = $model->getReport($validFormData['start_date'], $validFormData['end_date'], $validFormData['start_hour'], $validFormData['end_hour'], $access_token);

    // Set the data on the chart
    if ($report_data !== false) {
        $chart_status = true;
        $start_date = $validFormData['start_date'];
        $end_date = $validFormData['end_date'];
        $start_hour = $validFormData['start_hour'];
        $end_hour = $validFormData['end_hour'];
        $success = $report_data['success'];
        $failed = $report_data['failed'];
    } else {
        $chart_status = false;
    }
} else {
        // Report was found, get the data and print them
        $chart_status = true;
        $start_date = $validFormData['start_date'];
        $end_date = $validFormData['end_date'];
        $start_hour = $validFormData['start_hour'];
        $end_hour = $validFormData['end_hour'];
        $success = $existence_status['success'];
        $failed = $existence_status['failed'];
}
```

I just found out that if the returned value from the call of the getReportExistenceStatus is an array, it will go in the if instead of the else.

Here is the value of the $existence_status (got it from the var_dump) :

```php
array (size=2)
  'success' => int 100
  'failed' => int 0
```

But it still goes in the if statement instead of the else.

I've found a way to get around that problem (I'm using `php !is_array($existance_status)` as condition), but that really perturbate me, because, afaik, an filled array is not considered as "true", no ?

**Is that normal ?**

Comment: Yes a non-empty array loosely evaluates to `true`.

Comment: @AbraCadaver oh wow, that's... that's really dumb. Why ? An empty should be considered as an array, not as a bool.

Comment: https://www.php.net/manual/en/types.comparisons.php

Comment: @AbraCadaver haha, funny PHP. Alright, thank you ! Should I write an answer or you'll write it ?

Comment: I've seen duplicates and it will be closed...

Comment: @Epodax oh ! I haven't seen it. I'll mark it as my answer, thank you :)

Comment: @LeRouteur that's actually not that dumb, it's rather unexpectedly putting an array var in a condition that could be considered dumb (no offense lol). In this, PHP is smarter than Javascript, where even an empty array is truthy(!!!)

Comment: @Kaddath hmm... I haven't thinked it that way, I guess you're right :)